# Splitting text in different TextViews SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, textview, mkmapview

I have a big paragraph i want to add to a view. But the problem i am having is the first textview is small and then under it i have a map view. After the map view i want the text to continue from where it stopped in the first textview. I put an example below to show exactly what i mean.

```
@IBOutlet var firstSection: UITextView!
@IBOutlet var articleMapView: MKMapView!
@IBOutlet var secondSection: UITextView!
```

I want have a text above to map and and below it.

Comment: Your question is not clear please provide some details

Comment: Alright i changed it up so don’t nee to do that anymore. What i want to do now is resize the content to fix the textview. So if i have one line of text i want the textview to be one line and if i have 40 lines the textview should resize to fit that